# SQL Server 2005 LEFT JOIN?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I've the TABLE_1 with fields from A to Z.
I've also the TABLE_2 with fields B, G and P.

How can i found all records from TABLE_1 **that NOT**:

```
TABLE_1.B = TABLE_2.B
TABLE_1.G = TABLE_2.G
TABLE_1.P = TABLE_2.P
```

in SQL Server 2005 ?

Comment: Are those conditions inclusive or exclusive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.*
    FROM TABLE_1 t1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                         FROM TABLE_2 t2
                         WHERE t1.B = t2.B
                             AND t1.G = t2.G
                             AND t1.P = t2.P)
```